# Unable to locate Component

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, sybase

When we are using delphi-10 exe we are getting below issue,but i couldnt find this file in my machine where I installed delphi10

"This application failed to start becuase rtl140.bpl was not found.Re-installing the application may fix this problem"

Comment: Did you try to follow the suggestion and re-installed?

Comment: It's not Delphi 10. Delphi 2010 is version 14.

Answer (score 3):

Your executable is compiled with runtime packages and requires them to run; you should deploy them on the target computer during installation. Alternatively, you could turn off runtime packages (compiler options) and have a stand-alone executable.

On a computer where Delphi is installed the runtime packages should be installed in the system directory; Delphi IDE itself is compiled with runtime packages.